# Ubuntu 16.04 showing blank black screen

Tags: boot, lenovo

[image]

I have a USB which will connect directly to my workstation server, however I boot my laptop to BIOS, then Legacy support, and change the boot priority... I can see after restart it appear ubuntu 16.04 and fixing code, after that I am getting only black screen.

Laptop model is Lenovo Ideapad S145  (Core i5 10th Gen) with preinstalled Windows 10

Comment: Please clarify your release, Ubuntu desktop & server releases use a *yy.mm* (year.month) format, and there was no release in 2016-September.  Yes there are specialist releases that use *yy* only, but they are specialist, and no 19 release

Comment: sorry it was ubuntu 16,04 i have also attached the image in above post may be this will help you to resolve my  @guiverc